# How to handle many large Localizable.strings files?

Tags: ios, xcode

In my xcode project i try to handle many Localizable.strings files to create my app in many different languages. Each Localizable.strings file is kind of large (more than 400 key/value pairs).
Now i am getting into trouble when something in the app is changing. For example i add a new feature and have to add strings in every language in every file. There could be a problem when a string in (for example) russian is much longer than in english. Or i miss a language when adding the new string. Or i make a spelling error in a language file.

My question is: Is there a tool or other possibily to handle those big localization files? Something to handle the length of text? And a comiler configuration to warn if a used key is not present in any of the language files?

Would be very thankful for help/advises!!

Comment: I think you must handle this by your own...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on GitHub: https://github.com/nst/objc_strings

Very easy to use and integrate in xcode. Finds keys in localization file which are not used in code and finds also strings in code which have no reference to localization file.

Nice work!